# IEnumerable return First

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
    public IEnumerable<Report> GetReport(int reportId)
    {
        var dbReport = dbContext.ReportsTbl.Where(w =>w.ID == reportId);
        return dbReport;

   }
```

What I like to do though us to get First

If I do:

```
    public IEnumerable<Report> GetReport(int reportId)
    {
        var dbReport = dbContext.ReportsTbl.First(w =>w.ID == reportId);
        return dbReport;
   }
```

How do I get it to do First(). It is complaining about it being IEnumerable.

Comment: Try use FirstOrDefault() method, if you use First() method on empty or null list you get exception

Comment: @Jacek You can use `First()` if there must be at least one. Using `FirstOrDefault()` on a list that is null would throw a `NullReference` exception btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the method signature to return only a single object instead of a collection:

```
public Report GetReport(int reportId)
{
    var dbReport = dbContext.ReportsTbl.First(w =>w.ID == reportId);
    return dbReport;
}
```

If for some reason you do actually want a collection containing only the first element you could use `.Take(1)` instead of `First`.

Answer (score 2):

`First` returns the first element as type `Report`. Since its just one item, it does not return an enumerable.

You have two options:

```
public Report GetReport(int reportId)
{
    var dbReport = dbContext.ReportsTbl.First(w =>w.ID == reportId);
    return dbReport;
}
```

This example will return just one report, instead of a bunch (an enumerable) of reports.

```
public IEnumerable<Report> GetReport(int reportId)
{
    var dbReport = dbContext.ReportsTbl.Where(w =>w.ID == reportId).Take(1);
    return dbReport;
}
```

This example will return just one report, but it will be wrapped inside of an enumerable. You can think of this as a set of just one report.